# Informatica PowerCenter Install Requirements

Tags: informatica

I have a laptop where I'd like to use informatica powercenter 10.5.2 (Client). How do I get started with building transformations where my source are excel files (.xlsx) and convert to flat files ? What other software would I need to get this going locally for educational purposes?

I already installed:
Informatica 10.5.2
-PowerCenter Developer
-PowerCenter Designer
-PowerCenter Repository Manager
-PowerCenter Workflow Manager
-PowerCenter Workflow Monitor

Any info would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi - this is not really the right forum to ask for a tutorial on how to use Informatica. I’d start by reading the documentation, which is pretty good, and there are plenty of online resources that a quick search will turn up

Comment: Minimum requirements are `50 GB disk space, 8 GB RAM, and 8 cores.`  You can check https://docs.informatica.com/content/dam/source/GUID-4/GUID-41956D41-73C2-44E5-84A2-8E315824CFE8/6/en/IN_1052_InstallationForPowerCenterAndDataQuality_en.pdf pls

Comment: If the goal is to transform excel file to CSVs, then I'd really look for other solution. PowerCenter doesn't really work well with excel. And is not meant for local deployment and use. Try Talend Open Studio.